# Azure Error Processing Request

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android on Android Studio.

I was working on my project when seem I run into some issues while making queries to the Azure SQL Database, where I suspect there's some school firewall in play (for it worked back at home).

[image: Error while processing request]

Just to be sure that it isn't a code error, the screenshot below returns the result of running the downloaded ToDoList sample project; it tells me there's an error processing request for every repeated run.

Logcat:

```
    07-23 17:58:35.540 2359-2359/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (GetConfigTask) got error statusCode=-1.
    07-23 17:58:35.543 2359-13322/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ctxmgr: [DailyCheckinOperation]Failed daily get config: network status=-1`
```

Is there any way to ensure connection when I am at school? 
please and thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i restarted the computer and it worked...

thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more information on the Error or exception will be helpful.

If you are access Azure SQL database directly from the mobile app, then yes the firewall will block your access.  [Firewall settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-manage-firewall-using-portal)

A better way to the do this is for the mobile app to access a web API app; where the API app can access the Azure SQL database. There is also a setting in Azure SQL database to enable access from Azure services.

Comment: hi could you elaborate your first point? did you want the full logcat?// i edited the firewall settings to no avail// i will look into your suggestion about the web api thanks!

Comment: Azure Mobile Apps SDK to access the Azure SQL database. But you can debug the app line by line and catch the exception to get a detailed error.

Comment: I guess you used this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library

You can try and catch line with "MobileServiceClient" and see what the exception is when the app connects to the mobile service client.

**Also I think I miss understood your question first. You are using a web service to access Azure SQL database already; since the Azure Mobile SDK actually access a webapp in Azure. So, you don't need to create another API app. Sorry for the misunderstanding